# Getting the warning " ISO C90 forbids variable-size array" in gcc compiler while compiling C90 code

Tags: gcc-warning, c89

I am compiling my C90 c code in gcc . I am getting the warning`ISO C90 forbids variable-size array` while making the declaration like

`int symbols[nc];`

Where nc is integer whose value is read from the input file. The values on the input files are varied so i can't keep a constant value. How can I get rid of it? Is it indeed necessary to resolve this warning or we can simply ignore it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get that warning because C90 does not support [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

You'll either have to switch gcc to C99 mode (which does support vla) , by using the -std=c99 or std=gnu99 command line flag, or rewrite your code to dynamically allocate memory or use a fixed size array.

The warning just tells you that you're not conforming to C90 in this case, but it's otherwise safe. Ignoring a warning should really not be an option though.

Comment: If gcc is the only compiler that will ever see this code, adding `-Wno-vla` to the invocation is safer than getting into the habit of ignoring warnings.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Amongst all google results for this topic, you are the only one who tells about this option.